# Display null value in record Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to display '0' value in Avg Delay Departure table based on `STATION` in Schedule table.
Here's the Schedule table,

```
+---------+---------+----------+
| Station | On Time | Schedule |
+---------+---------+----------+
| AMQ     |     174 |      202 |
| AMS     |      21 |       27 |
| BDJ     |     182 |      210 |
| BDO     |      56 |       62 |
| BEJ     |      59 |       62 |
| BIK     |      74 |       93 |
| BKK     |      81 |       87 |
| BKS     |      73 |       87 |
| BMU     |      60 |       60 |
| BOM     |       2 |        7 |
| BPN     |     413 |      452 |
+---------+---------+----------+
```

Here's the Avg Delay table,

```
+---------+---------------------+
| Station | Avg Delay Departure |
+---------+---------------------+
| AMQ     | 53.21               |
| AMS     | 49.5                |
| BDJ     | 60.78               |
| BDO     | 67.66               |
| BEJ     | 46.33               |
| BIK     | 47.53               |
| BKK     | 55.5                |
| BKS     | 67.56               |
| BOM     | 45.2                |
| BPN     | 53.81               |
+---------+---------------------+
```

Pay attention to `BMU` record in Schedule table. It has 60 schedules and 60 on time so there's no delay. I want to display the `BMU` record in Avg Delay table with value of '0' for `Avg Delay Departure` column. My current query don't display that.
Here's the query for Avg Delay table,

```
SELECT DEPAIRPORT AS STATION, to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate) + avg(cast(ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF_LC as date) - cast(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC as date)), 'sssss'))/60 as DEPAVERAGE
FROM DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS
WHERE ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF_LC IS NOT NULL AND SERVICETYPE IN ('J','G') AND (ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF_LC - SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC)*24*60 > '+000000015 00:00:00.000000000' 
AND STATUS IN ('Scheduled') AND
      TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN '2018-04-14' AND '2018-05-14'
GROUP BY DEPAIRPORT
ORDER BY STATION ASC;
```

Comment: You're going to have to move sum of the `WHERE` logic into the select clause.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen do I have to just move the entire WHERE logic or I need to add CASE WHEN in nested SELECT clause?

Comment: Case when in nested select.  Your logic is too complex for me to guess an answer.  I'll bet we could simplify your query.

Comment: Your sample data does not concern to your query. What is the use of `Schedule` table in your query? Why dont you post structure and sample data for table `DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS`?