# ORA-00904 Invalid identifier on JOIN oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I got error ORA-00904: "S"."FLIGHTLEGREF": invalid identifier on this

```
JOIN STAT_1 S ON D.FLIGHTLEGREF = S.FLIGHTLEGREF
```

Here's my query

```
WITH STAT_1 AS (SELECT DEPAIRPORT AS STATION
              FROM DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS
              WHERE ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF_LC IS NOT NULL AND SERVICETYPE IN ('J','G') AND STATUS IN ('Scheduled') AND TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN '2018-04-14' AND '2018-05-14'
              ORDER BY STATION ASC) 
SELECT S.STAT_1 AS STATION, COALESCE((SELECT to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate) + avg(cast(ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF_LC as date) - cast(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC as date)), 'sssss'))/60
                                     FROM DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS
                                     WHERE (ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF_LC - SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC)*24*60 > '+000000015 00:00:00.000000000'), 0) as DEPAVERAGE
FROM DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS D
     JOIN STAT_1 S ON D.FLIGHTLEGREF = S.FLIGHTLEGREF
WHERE ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF_LC IS NOT NULL AND SERVICETYPE IN ('J','G') AND --(ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF_LC - SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC)*24*60 > '+000000015 00:00:00.000000000' AND 
      STATUS IN ('Scheduled') AND TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN '2018-04-14' AND '2018-05-14'
GROUP BY S.STAT_1
ORDER BY STATION ASC;
```

Anybody have idea?

Comment: It's very clear: Your `S` table has no column named `FLIGHTLEGREF`! That `S` table - `STAT_1` has only one column named `STATION` as you define in your CTE.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach I've tested the `S` table and actually it has `FLIGHTLEGREF` because it comes from the same `DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS` table.

Comment: Yes it come from table `DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS` but as in your CTE, you only `SELECT depairport AS station` from it, so your `STAT_1` only have one column named `station`. You should read more about CTE, and subquery to understand this. You are using it completely wrong: use wrong column, wrong name: `S.STAT_1`, `S.FLIGHTLEGREF`.

Comment: You seem to want to join the grouped rows from  a cte on the same table and similar conditions. If you could post sample data and expected o/p and tell us what you are trying to achieve, a much better query could be written for u.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Is it possible to group rows from a cte on the same table and similar conditions? I'm actually trying to solve this case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382438/display-null-value-in-record-oracle

Comment: Farhan: Even in that question @PhamX.Bach posed a question and you don't seem to have responded

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: Please learn to format your code. Readability is a feature, especially when you are asking a bunch of strangers on the internet to help you. Code which is laid out clearly is easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You created `STAT_1` table that contains only one column-`STATION`, you can execute its query and see.

Therefore you need to add to its query the column of your condition:

```
 ,FLIGHTLEGREF
```

And replace `S.STAT_1` with `STAT_1.STATION` which is the available column in `STAT_1`.

```
WITH STAT_1 AS (SELECT DEPAIRPORT AS STATION, FLIGHTLEGREF
              FROM DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS
              WHERE ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF_LC IS NOT NULL AND SERVICETYPE IN ('J','G') AND STATUS IN ('Scheduled') AND TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN '2018-04-14' AND '2018-05-14'
              ORDER BY STATION ASC) 
SELECT STAT_1.STATION, COALESCE((SELECT to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate) + avg(cast(ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF_LC as date) - cast(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC as date)), 'sssss'))/60
                                     FROM DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS
                                     WHERE (ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF_LC - SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC)*24*60 > '+000000015 00:00:00.000000000'), 0) as DEPAVERAGE
FROM DBODSXML4OPS.XML4OPS D
     JOIN STAT_1 ON D.FLIGHTLEGREF = STAT_1.FLIGHTLEGREF
WHERE ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF_LC IS NOT NULL AND SERVICETYPE IN ('J','G') AND --(ACTUAL_BLOCKOFF_LC - SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC)*24*60 > '+000000015 00:00:00.000000000' AND 
      STATUS IN ('Scheduled') AND TO_CHAR(SCHEDULED_DEPDT_LC, 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN '2018-04-14' AND '2018-05-14'
GROUP BY STAT_1.STATION
ORDER BY STAT_1.STATION ASC;
```